# Mapbox - extruding buildings in custom layer

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

After seeing 3d buildings in mapbox here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/  I've decided to create a custom layer with only 3 buildings of my own (custom ones, one of which is in construction in reality), but I'm having problems extruding those buildings in mapbox view. I'm using same code as in example and only building contours shows up on the ground, cant make them look like 3d buildings. Any advices here?

To be more specific: 
1. created building with JOSM, 
2. exported to geojson file
3. imported to mapbox studio
4. trying to use layer in code, but only building countours appear in map - not an actual 3d shape.

Here's a screenshot from my mapbox studio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Wvb.jpg - building layer is default one which shows buildings, but building_custom does not. Also, why my building_custom layer has green line near its name instead of blue one, like building layer does?

I've been trying to fix this for 2 days, not sure what I'm doing wrong with mapbox. As a proof that buildings actually exists, check here, where it displays correctly https://osmbuildings.org/?lat=40.71604&lon=-74.0362&zoom=17.8&rotation=-54&tilt=28 (middle building, reverse C shape front).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your screenshot is up to date, you're currently styling your building_custom layer as a fill layer. In order to make them 3D you'll need to change this to a fill-extrusion layer (next to "Type" — the fill-extrusion layer type is the one that looks like a windmill). Once it's a fill-extrusion layer you'll be able to adjust its height in the Style panel.

As to your other question I think what you're asking is why building_custom has a light purple line next to its name? If this is your question, the color coding has to do with what source-layer a layer's data comes from. The default building layer comes from the "building" source layer in Mapbox Streets; your custom building layer is from a different source layer. (All the place-* layers come from the same source-layer — "place-label" in Mapbox Streets — which is why they all have the same color.)

Comment: Yea it does extrude my building, but it ignores settings I've added with JOSM, like min_height, height, building:min_level, building:levels, etc. Because my building is not an usual shape, it looks like this __[] where lower part is like 9 floors and tall part is 69 floors. I imagine I could create 2 layers and make it work, but just wondering if there's a better way to display a complex building in mapbox?

Comment: I see. A `fill-extrusion` in Mapbox is just a polygonal prism, so if you'd like to show a building with two different heights, it'll need to be two different features (if the overlap, they'll appear to be joined when rendered, which is probably the effect you're looking for). As for settings you've ignored in JOSM you'll need to use [property functions](https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-manual-styles/#enable-property-function) to set `fill-extrusion-height` and `fill-extrusion-base` to the values you want.